# Changing a variable within a select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'll be honest, I'm not even sure if what I am trying to do is feasible.  Normally I'd code this externally but I need to get it working within a stored procedure or find another way around.

It's effectively a timetable.  I have a series of events with a start and end time, some of which clash but not always with the same start/end.  There are set rest periods between each group of events that will break them into blocks during, effectively having 4 blocks per day.  I need to be able to group all that clash together to find the earliest start and the latest end time, and sum another column of number of attendees.

What I currently am trying is using lag to see if the event falls within the scope of the previous one, this works fine but I can't see a way to group them.  I was hoping to use a variable that only increments in the else section of the case statement but that seems to be a no go.

```
declare @MyVar Integer
set @MyVar = 1

SELECT        RoomID, RoomNo, Date, DayOfYear, StartTime, EndTime, ActivityID,
case when 
LAG(StartTime,1) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityID) between starttime and endtime then LAG(ActivityID,1) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)
when LAG(endTime,1) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityID) between starttime and endtime then LAG(ActivityID,1) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityID)
else  0 end as ClashesWith
FROM            TTData
WHERE        (RoomNo = 'Room1')
ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree completely here?  Bit out of my comfort zone to be honest.  I could write a VBscript easily enough but never done anything like this in TSQL.

EDIT:
Sorry, in my head I was clear but reading back I'm blatantly not!

- I have a table of every event, regardless of clashes
- I want to assign an ID to each group of clashes

Hopefully this is an image of the data as it stands, with the far right column being my output so far:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5gKz.png

What I'd like is for the last column to have the same number in for group 1, a different number for group 2,3,4.... and a 0 if no clash is found.

EDIT2:  Input data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   RoomID INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,RoomNo VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,DayOfYear INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,StartTime DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,EndTime DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,ActivityID INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,FIELD7 VARCHAR(11)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 09:00:00.000','2018-01-03 10:30:00.000',221456);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 09:00:00.000','2018-01-03 10:30:00.000',222129);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 09:00:00.000','2018-01-03 10:30:00.000',222251);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 09:00:00.000','2018-01-03 10:30:00.000',222389);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 09:00:00.000','2018-01-03 10:30:00.000',222527);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 10:45:00.000','2018-01-03 12:15:00.000',221491);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 10:45:00.000','2018-01-03 12:15:00.000',222160);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 10:45:00.000','2018-01-03 12:15:00.000',222286);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 10:45:00.000','2018-01-03 12:15:00.000',222424);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 10:45:00.000','2018-01-03 12:15:00.000',222562);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 10:45:00.000','2018-01-03 12:15:00.000',224183);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 13:45:00.000','2018-01-03 15:15:00.000',221921);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 13:45:00.000','2018-01-03 15:15:00.000',223167);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 15:30:00.000','2018-01-03 17:00:00.000',221956);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',3,'2018-01-03 15:30:00.000','2018-01-03 17:00:00.000',223202);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 09:00:00.000','2018-01-04 10:30:00.000',222664);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 09:00:00.000','2018-01-04 10:30:00.000',222800);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 09:00:00.000','2018-01-04 10:30:00.000',222968);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 09:00:00.000','2018-01-04 10:30:00.000',223098);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 10:45:00.000','2018-01-04 12:15:00.000',222698);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 10:45:00.000','2018-01-04 12:15:00.000',222831);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 10:45:00.000','2018-01-04 12:15:00.000',223004);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 10:45:00.000','2018-01-04 12:15:00.000',223132);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 13:45:00.000','2018-01-04 15:15:00.000',221507);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 13:45:00.000','2018-01-04 15:15:00.000',221782);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 13:45:00.000','2018-01-04 15:15:00.000',222320);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 13:45:00.000','2018-01-04 15:15:00.000',222458);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 13:45:00.000','2018-01-04 15:15:00.000',223426);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 15:30:00.000','2018-01-04 17:00:00.000',221541);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 15:30:00.000','2018-01-04 17:00:00.000',221816);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 15:30:00.000','2018-01-04 17:00:00.000',222354);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 15:30:00.000','2018-01-04 17:00:00.000',222492);
INSERT INTO mytable(RoomID,RoomNo,DayOfYear,StartTime,EndTime,ActivityID) VALUES (308,'P1C1',4,'2018-01-04 15:30:00.000','2018-01-04 17:00:00.000',223459);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We are going to need a lot more information here as this is not clear at all. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You just want a list of every booking?  Or every booking that clashes with another?  If booking one starts first and then clashes with booking two, do you want to see both, or just the one that started later, or just the one that was booked later?  If a booking clashes with more than one booking, what do you want to see *(1 = 8am to 10am, 2 = 9am to 11am, 3 = 10am to 12pm : 2 clashes with 1 AND 3...)*?  If you can give a more complete example of the behaviour you want then we can show you how to approach it...

Comment: Thanks, will read that now.

Comment: And please don't upload images of data. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Realised there was a much simpler solution, for my own problem at least.  I have a maximum of 4 clashing events at present so I just used 6 when statements lagging back 1-6 rows.  This means i can include any results with a 0 in the clash column in my main data and group anything with an ID back to the initial event.  It's not perfect but it suits my needs for now.

```
SELECT        RoomID, RoomNo, DayOfYear, StartTime, EndTime, ActivityOccurrenceID,
case 
when starttime between LAG(StartTime,6) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID) and DATEADD(mi, -1, LAG(endTime,6) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)) or endTime between LAG(StartTime,6) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID) and DATEADD(mi, -1, LAG(endTime,6) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)) then LAG(ActivityOccurrenceID,6) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)
when starttime between LAG(StartTime,5) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID) and DATEADD(mi, -1, LAG(endTime,5) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)) or endTime between LAG(StartTime,5) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID) and DATEADD(mi, -1, LAG(endTime,5) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)) then LAG(ActivityOccurrenceID,5) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)
when starttime between LAG(StartTime,4) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID) and DATEADD(mi, -1, LAG(endTime,4) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)) or endTime between LAG(StartTime,4) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID) and DATEADD(mi, -1, LAG(endTime,4) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)) then LAG(ActivityOccurrenceID,4) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)
when starttime between LAG(StartTime,3) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID) and DATEADD(mi, -1, LAG(endTime,3) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)) or endTime between LAG(StartTime,3) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID) and DATEADD(mi, -1, LAG(endTime,3) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)) then LAG(ActivityOccurrenceID,3) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)
when starttime between LAG(StartTime,2) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID) and DATEADD(mi, -1, LAG(endTime,2) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)) or endTime between LAG(StartTime,2) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID) and DATEADD(mi, -1, LAG(endTime,2) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)) then LAG(ActivityOccurrenceID,2) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)
when starttime between LAG(StartTime,1) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID) and DATEADD(mi, -1, LAG(endTime,1) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)) or endTime between LAG(StartTime,1) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID) and DATEADD(mi, -1, LAG(endTime,1) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)) then LAG(ActivityOccurrenceID,1) OVER(ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID)
else  0 end as ClashesWith
FROM            myTable
ORDER BY RoomID, DayOfYear, StartTime, ActivityOccurrenceID
```